# How do I activate code completion for case statements?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, code-completion

In more recent Delphi versions it is possible to use code completion to code all the cases in a case statement at once, for e.g. enumerated types.

But whatever I try, I can't get it to work. What should I start to type, then what hotkey to use? Maybe I'm missing a Tools/Options setting, although I don't suspect that, because it's a manual operation.

Comment: I'm not even sure Delphi comes with such a thing. The only live template that writes a case statement is very basic indeed. Type case and press CTRL+J.

Comment: 'Tab'. Given 'al' is a variable of TAlignment, write 'case', press 'tab' or 'space', write 'al' in place of 'True', then press 'Tab'. If it fills in taLeftJustify: .. etc. then it works there as much as it works here (i.e. it doesn't do always what you expect it to do).

Comment: usually typing "Case" <SPACE> <VariableNameOfType> <TAB> will do what you are looking for. I'm loosing it when Variable is not of the Type, Type while typing unknown (declaration missing), or when editing an existing entry.

Comment: I've never had this successfully do what you all describe in my Delphi installations. Ho hum. Wonder what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @David: That surprises me. I love this feature, when it works (which, admittedly, is only sometimes).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Exit the case variable field with a Tab and the IDE will auto-complete the case options if your variable is of a enumerated type.

[image: typing a case statement]

1. In the proper place in the code editor Type `case` <kbd>space</kbd>
2. The IDE adds a *case template* and presents a blue rectangle *field* where you type the variable name for the case statement
3. Write the name of that variable and
4. Exit the *field* with the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key
5. The IDE adds all the enum values to the *case template*.

[image]

Comment: +1, although I'd replace "The IDE adds..." by "The IDE hopefully adds..."

Comment: +1 Can you modify the template so that it uses more sane indentation?

Comment: @David: This indentation looks very standard to me. What is wrong with it?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I'd want to have the labels at the same indentation as `case`. And I'd want the semi-colons indented on new lines.

Comment: @David - See [here](http://caryjensen.blogspot.com/2011_04_01_archive.html). You want to run your own active script instead of 'PopulateCase'.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, standard formatting in Delphi is indentation of case labels (and semicolons indented on new lines). But I agree, I'm more pleased with no indentation for the case labels.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, FYI, Delphi XE3 has an option to change case labels indentation. (Tools / Options / Formatter / Delphi / Indentation / Indent case labels). There's a lot of other stuff you can control from the Formatter section of the Options window.

Comment: The reason I could not get it to work anymore was that my "Tools / Options / Code Insight / Code template completion / Auto Complete" was off. This is a requirement for it to work.